# Sum of elements within an array within list

Tags: python, arrays, list, sum

I'm trying to calculate the np.sum of the elements within each array. I tried in stead of `np.sum(outcome_list[0] == 'H'` to just leave it as `np.sum(outcome_list[j] == 'H'` so that each "list" would have its own data set on the total number of heads, but it didn't like it. The bigger question is, how would I construct an array with a given base list and the action to be done in each element of that list?

[image]

**EDIT:**

*the throw_a_coin definition*

```
def throw_a_coin(N):
    return np.random.choice(['H','T'], size=N)
N =40
```

*trials (as shown above) is the set to be acted upon*

```
for i in trials:
    throws = throw_a_coin(i)
    outcome_list.append(throws)

for j in outcome_list:
    print("Number of Heads:", np.sum(outcome_list[0] == 'H'))
    print (j)
```

**EDIT 2:**

problem resolved with the one shown below, however I'm getting more than 13 numbers for "probabilities" - it seems that the system is running through the trials list more than once.

```
def throw_a_coin(N):
    return np.random.choice(['H','T'], size=N)

trials = [10, 30, 50, 70, 100, 130, 170, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000]

for i in trials:
    throws = throw_a_coin(i)
    outcome_list.append(throws)

probabilities = []

for j in outcome_list:
    print("Number of Heads:", np.sum(j == 'H'))
    print("Number of Throws:", len(j))
    print("p = Number of Heads/Total Throws:", (np.sum(j == 'H'))/len(j))
    probabilities.append((np.sum(j =='H'))/len(j))
    print (j)
    print("\n")

print(probabilities)
```

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of heads?

Comment: Can you please attach the code instead of the photo of the code?

Comment: @Rishav - yes, count the number of heads per each of the trials

Comment: @Sohum Sachdev - edited post with the code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there! You just needed to replace

```
print("Number of Heads:", np.sum(outcome_list[0] == 'H'))
```

with

```
print("Number of Heads:", np.sum(j == 'H'))
```

Here is the complete answer:

```
trials = [10, 30, 50, 70, 100, 130, 170, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000]

N =40
def throw_a_coin(N):
    return np.random.choice(['H','T'], size=N)

outcome_list = []
for i in trials:
    throws = throw_a_coin(i)
    outcome_list.append(throws)

for j in outcome_list:
    print("Number of Heads:", np.sum(j == 'H'))
    print (j)
```

Comment: I've also added "EDIT 2" to the question - it seems that it's running through "trials" more than once?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print("Number of Heads:", (j == 'H').sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

If `output_list` would be a numpy array and if each row in the matrix represent each trial, you can get the sum in an efficient way as follows:

```
head_sum = output_list.sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a list comprehension followed by a `len` call.

```
for j in outcome_list:
    print("Number of Heads:", len([x for x in j if x == 'H'])
    print (j)
```

***DISCLAIMER***: I have zero experience with Numpy. However, this would be the general Pythonic way to do it without resorting to `count`.

Comment: This is pretty good, but I would recommend `sum(1 for x in j if x == 'H')`  By using a generator comprehension, we avoid actually building the list of `H`s.  It's a tiny difference, but I just thought I would mention it.